# How to get apps for iPhone and iPad on mac?

Tags: mac, ios-appstore, mac-appstore, ios

How to get iPhone and iPad apps that are not available in the App Store on your Mac if I don't have an iPhone or iPad?

Comment: Is there a particular app you want?

Answer (score 1):

Apple Silicon Macs can run some (but not all) apps for iOS and iPadOS. You can purchase and download them from the Mac App Store.

If they don't show in the Mac App Store, then either they don't work with macOS, or the developer doesn't want them to run on macOS (e.g. because they have a Mac version.)